# How to efficiently determine when changes occur in event lists

Tags: php, sorting

We have a system that stores event information.
There is a primary list of events as well as a secondary list, these may overlap.
Secondary lists are combined with the primary based on 3 main rules.

1. Default - only displayed when no events are current
2. Events - only displayed when primary events are current
3. Override - displayed in stead of events

A new 3rd party system we have to integrate with means we need to get each of the different states throughout the days of what events/secondary events should be showing.
Eg, from 9-5 these events are current based on the timings/ rules, but then after 5 these events are current based on the timings and rules.

A simple example

**Primary Events**

1. Event alpha | 10:30 - 14:30
2. Event bravo | 14:00 - 16:00
3. Event charlie | 18:30 - 20:00

**Secondary Events**

1. Event zulu | 00:00 - 23:59 | default
2. Event yankee | 09:00 - 11:00 | default
3. Event xray | 09:00 - 11:30 | events
4. Event whiskey | 19:00 - 19:15 | override

Just on this very small example this would result as the following lists that we would need to generate

00:00-09:00
Event zulu

09:00-10:30
Event zulu
Event yankee

10:30-11:30
Event alpha
Event xray

11:30-14:00
Event alpha

14:00-14:30
Event alpha
Event bravo

14:30-16:00
Event bravo

16:00-18:30
Event zulu

18:30-19:00
Event charlie

19:00-19:15
Event whiskey

19:15-20:00
Event charlie

20:00-23:59
Event zulu

This is a tiny example in production there is usually hundreds to thousands of events over many days. 
At present the only end points deal with this problem dynamically on the fly, this third party system requires we provide the data in this way.

It's all written in php, and we have the primary and secondary event lists in an array each.

What is the most efficient way of making these lists ?

We have considered doing a minute by minute check, but this seems horribly inefficient and I'm hoping there is a better way.

Comment: I cannot see why this is a question. The algorithm you desire is not trivial? I would simply loop through the minimum time interval you desire and at each point in time, compute the events. The rules are simple; you only need an appropriate data structure to map a point in time to an event. This could be an array with an entry for the event start and end; since you iterate, the current events are obvious.

Comment: @FrankHileman This was what I planned to do to start with, but it felt like a hack and that I must be missing something - I've not had to do anything like this before. Perhaps this is the way forward, just wanted to see if anyone had any different thoughts. Since posting I've started wondering about duplicating the arrays then sorting one of each by start time and the other by end time, then stepping through each element in each array to determine when the next change needs to occur... but I don't know if this approach is more or less of a hack than stepping through minute by minute...

Comment: To reduce the size of the array, don't have one array element per unit of time. Instead, have an array of data structures, where each element contains a time, a list (or array) of event starts, and a list of event ends. In this way, you can iterate through every important time, without iterating per unit of time. The array must be sorted by time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So heres what I did in the end, rather than looping through each minute of each day and checking what should be showing I created a list of all the start and stop times (in one single list) then removed duplicates and sorted them in order.

This way I can just cycled through that array and that will give me the start/end times when things change.